# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: nonce generation function failed or private key is invalid in Ganache

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, modifiers, revert-opcode, ganache-cli

In Go I am using **go-ethereum** to read data from the ethereum smart contract. My smart contract is maintained with truffle.

I am trying to fetch candidate information based on candidate id. I have a modifier in the solidity that checks if given id exists or not as

```
    /**
     *  Check if candidate exists
     */
    modifier candidateExists(uint256 candidateId) {
        require(candidates[candidateId].exists, "No Candidate.");

        _;
    }
```

Everything works perfectly fine if I pass valid **candidateId**. But exception occurs if candidates don't exist and revert.
Following is the error recorded in ganache-cli console

```
(node:31528) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: nonce generation function failed or private key is invalid
    at Object.t.sign (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:37:75864)
    at Object.sign (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:37:64863)
    at Object.t.ecsign (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:37:185991)
    at e.sign (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:17:104733)
    at e.sign (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:10:92594)
    at e.t.hash (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:37:243491)
    at e.u [as hash] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:10:89447)
    at c.combine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:2:159323)
    at new c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:2:158990)
    at Function.c.fromResults (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:2:160122)
    at readyCall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:17:120626)
(node:31528) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 26)
(node:31528) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Which version of ganache do you use ? Have you try upgrading ?

Comment: Ganache CLI v6.10.0-beta.2

Answer (score 0):

You need call this function with a CallOptions.

```go
yourContractInstance.CandidateExists(&bind.CallOpts{
    From: common.HexToAddress("Current Wallet Address"),
})
```